# Divide pdf exact equal half using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to divide a PDF into exactly 2 equal halves, saving them as "LeftPDF.pdf" and "RightPDF.pdf".

I tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
float width = psize.Width/2;
float height = psize.Height;
Document document = new Document(psize);
// target.pdf is A5 Portrait format
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(splitpath, FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
document.NewPage();
PdfImportedPage page1 =writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
document.Close();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, your question has been posted and answered before. This is yet another duplicate of your question: [Divide one page PDF file in two pages PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011829/divide-one-page-pdf-file-in-two-pages-pdf-file)

Take a closer look at the [TileInTwo](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/TileInTwo) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating a reader
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    // step 1
    Rectangle mediabox = new Rectangle(getHalfPageSize(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1)));
    Document document = new Document(mediabox);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer
        = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte content = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    int i = 1;
    while (true) {
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        content.addTemplate(page, 0, -mediabox.getHeight());
        document.newPage();
        content.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        if (++i > n)
            break;
        mediabox = new Rectangle(getHalfPageSize(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i)));
        document.setPageSize(mediabox);
        document.newPage();
    }
    // step 5
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}

public Rectangle getHalfPageSize(Rectangle pagesize) {
    float width = pagesize.getWidth();
    float height = pagesize.getHeight();
    return new Rectangle(width, height / 2);
}
```

In this example, we ask the `PdfReader` instance for the page size of the first page and we create a new rectangle with the same width and only half the height.

We then import each page in the document, and we add it twice on different pages:

- once on the odd pages with a negative `y` value to show the upper half of the original page,
- once on the even pages with `y = 0` to show the lower half of the original page.

As every page in the original document can have a different size, we may need to change the page size for every new couple of pages.

This example cuts a page in two with an upper part and a lower part. Use simple math and you can adapt the example to cut it in two with a left and a right part. This is done in the example [TileInTwo2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/TileInTwo2):

For instance:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating a reader
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    // step 1
    Rectangle mediabox = new Rectangle(getHalfPageSize(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1)));
    Document document = new Document(mediabox);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer
        = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte content = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    int i = 1;
    while (true) {
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        content.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        document.newPage();
        content.addTemplate(page, -mediabox.getWidth(), 0);
        if (++i > n)
            break;
        mediabox = new Rectangle(getHalfPageSize(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i)));
        document.setPageSize(mediabox);
        document.newPage();
    }
    // step 5
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}

public Rectangle getHalfPageSize(Rectangle pagesize) {
    float width = pagesize.getWidth();
    float height = pagesize.getHeight();
    return new Rectangle(width / 2, height);
}
```

You should have no problem to adapt this example so that different PDF documents are created instead of the one containing the left and right part. If that is problematic for you, please post another question.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply actually i am trying to divide pdf vertically like |L part page| |Right Part Page|. Above code dividing page into upper part and lower part